# С чем связано ограничение на объявление friend функций в локальных классах?

Tags: c++, классы

С чем связано ограничение на объявление friend функций в локальных классах?

```
class A {
    friend void foo(){}; // OK
};


int main() {
    class B {
        friend void foo(){}; // ERROR
    };
}
```

Comment: Не думаю, что для этого существует какое-то вразумительное объяснение. Просто такие правила "исторически сложились".

Comment: @Harry так в примере же B::foo() объявлена **в** main, а не за его пределами

Comment: @user323345 Я думаю, что это связано с ADL (поиск, зависящий от аргументов). Если локально перед объявлением класса объявить функцию, то код будет компилироваться.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Не будет он компилироваться.

Comment: @VTT Он будет компилироваться, если определение функции заменить на ее объявление в классе.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow А в таком случае получится, что слишком далеко отошли от исходного примера.

Comment: @VTT Я не заметил сначала, что функция определяется в классе.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Тут еще на самом деле еще заголовок вносит путаницу, написано - объявление, а в примере - сразу определение.

Comment: Не вижу тут проблем с ADL. Разумеется если доопределить ADL так, чтобы он умел находить такие функции по той же схеме, по какой он находит дружественные функции в нелокальных классах. Более того, начиная с C++11 (возможность `auto` типа возврата) локальные классы фактически перестали быть локальными.

Answer (score 2):

*Объявлять* дружественные функции к локальном классе вам никто не запрещает. В вашем примере срабатывает не ограничение на *объявление* дружественных функций как таковое, а ограничение на *определение* дружественных функций прямо внутри определения локального класса.

Можно сказать что ситуация проистекает из [особенностей использования *неквалифицированного имени* во friend-объявлениях в локальных классах](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#11). Квалифицированные имена во friend-объявлениях использовать можно обычным образом (т.е., как всегда с квалифицированными именами, такие friend-объявления должны ссылаться на уже известные функции)

```
void foo() {}

int main()
{
  class A {
    friend void foo(); // <- Так нельзя
  };

  class B {
    friend void ::foo(); // <- А так можно
  };
}
```

Особенность же неквалифицированного имени заключается в том, что по правилам friend-объявлений, такое объявление ссылается на сущность *в ближайшей охватывающей не-класс области видимости*. В вышеприведенном примере friend-объявление в классе `A` ссылается на имя функции `foo`, локальное в `main`.

Такая трактовка неквалифицированного имени необходима потому, что это - единственный способ, при помощи которого локальные классы могут ссылаться друг на друга. По понятным причинам квалифицированных имен у таких классов нет.

Что интересно, "спасти" такое friend-объявление еще можно, если насильно "притащить" в локальную область видимости объявление существующей функции с таким именем

```
void foo() {}

int main()
{
  void foo(); // Объявление ссылается на `::foo`

  class A {
    friend void foo(); // <- Так можно
    // Ссылается на локальное имя `foo` в main, которое ссылается на `::foo`
  };
}
```

Но к *определениям* новых функций (как в вашем примере) эта лазейка не относится - оно бы фактически пыталось *определить* локальную функцию в `main`.

---

Можно заметить: а почему бы не модифицировать спецификацию friend-объявлений и не сказать, что неквалифицированные имена в *определениях* ссылаются на сущности в ближайшей охватывающей области видимости уровня namespace?

Я не вижу технических ограничений для такой реализации. С тем только замечанием, что это приведет к разной трактовке неквалифицированных имен во friend-объявлениях и во friend-определениях. Что некрасиво.

---

Актуальность этой темы, кстати, потенциально выросла с C++14, в котором локальные классы стали совсем не такими локальными, какими они были раньше

```
auto foo() 
{
  struct S 
  {
    void bar() {}
  };

  return S();
}

int main() 
{
  auto a = foo();
  a.bar();

  decltype(a) b;
  b.bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что проблема связана с тем, что friend-объявление не вводит объявленную функцию в область объявления. Функция является невидимой. Поэтому не имеет смысла определять friend-функцию в области объявления локального класса.

Когда же такое определение friend-функции встречается в нелокальном объявлении класса, то может подключаться зависящий от аргумента поиск (ADL), который рассматривает ассоциативные пространства имен и таким образом находит объявленную в классе функцию.